# Insert two figures along one other figure

Tags: subfloats, includegraphics, subfig

I have 3 figures that I want to insert them as one figure in my document. I want to order them as the following
[image]

I use the following code

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,10pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \subfloat[aaa]{
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{Fig.jpg}
        \subfloat[bbb]{
            \includegraphics[width=6cm]{Fig.jpg}
            \hfill
            \includegraphics[width=6cm]{Fig.jpg}
        }
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But the result is as
[image]

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

With use of `tabular` table is simple:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,10pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[demo,   % in real document remove option "demo"
            export]{adjustbox} % it also call  "graphicx", 
                               % enable to move baseline to vertical center of image
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{multirow}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}{ *{2}{p{6cm}} }
\multirow{2}{=}{
\subfloat[aaa]{\includegraphics[valign=c]{Fig.jpg}}
                }
    &   \subfloat[bbb]{\includegraphics[valign=c]{Fig.jpg}}

        \subfloat[ccc]{\includegraphics[valign=c]{Fig.jpg}}
    \end{tabular}
\caption{My figure}
\label{fig:?}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One can put two images into one `\subfloat`, but you need a `\parbox`, `minipage` or (better) `varwidth`.

Note that the default baseline for `\subfloat` is the baseline (bottom) of the image, so you need `\raisebox` to center it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,10pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \raisebox{\dimexpr 0.5\depth-0.5\height}{%
        \subfloat[aaa]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}}%
    }\hfill
    \subfloat[bbb]{\parbox{6cm}{%
            \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-b}
            \par
            \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-c}%
        }%
    }\llap{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}% show baseline, debug only
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```